# File Watcher failing with no errors in PHPStorm

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm

When running my file watcher to compile/compress my SASS files, PHPStorm randomly decides to fail but with no errors. No changes are made to the output file and all that happens is the following output dialog appears.

[image: Output dialog showing no errors]

The Ruby path is in my System Env and running SASS via the terminal works fine:

[image: Running manually works]

Edit: Below is a screenshot of my File Watcher settings (as requested by @lena)

[image: Screenshot of File Watcher settings]

**Arguments:** *--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css --style compressed*

Has anyone got any thoughts as to what it could be?

Thanks

Gav

Comment: Please can you attach a screenshot of you file watcher settings?

Comment: thanks:) As you have 'Show console' set to 'Error', and the console is displayed, it means that some errors occur during compilation (thus output file doesn't change). I have no idea why the error is not displayed in console - works fine for me using similar settings. Does the issue happen always? I mean - can you normally see syntax errors in watcher console, or they are never shown?

Comment: Hi @lena - It was working fine up until Wednesday when every attempt both by modifying the file, or manually running the watcher in PHPStorm would not work and show the Output window with the command line arguments etc. When running it manually via the terminal, it would work everytime. One thing that could be the cause, is that it takes approximately 1 minute to complete (complex structure) however other colleagues running the same setup/code is having no problems what so ever?